# How to query metadata information other than using show syntax of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: metadata, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Is there a way to query the metadata information of Apache IoTDB other than using the "show" syntax? I know that for mqsql's query table information, it can use statement like "select * from information.column" to check metadata.

Wonder if IoTDB has similar statement function, and if so, how should I write that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Apache IoTDB cannot use `select` statement to query metadata. Metadata queries need to use the `show` series of queries in IoTDB.